# How to match words separated with single space vs words separated with multiple spaces

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I need to separate the key and values from the text that looks like below

> Student ID:  0
>   Department ID =          18432
>   Name                        XYZ

```
Subjects:
Computer Architecture
Advanced Network Security 2
```

In the above example Student ID, Department ID and Name are the keys and 0,18432, XYZ are values. The keys are separated from the values either by :,= or multiple spaces. I tried reg ex such as

```
    $line =~ /(([\w\(\)]*\s)*)([=:\s?]?)\s*(\S.*)?$/;
    $key   = $2;
    $colon=$3;
    $value = $4;
```

The problem I am facing is identifying when a word is separated with single space and when it is separated by more than one.

The output I get is
line is Student ID: 0
key is Student , value is ID: 0
while I want key is Student ID and value is 0. For lines like Subjects: and Computer Architecture, the key should have Subjects and Computer Architecture. I have logic later when there is no value or colon, I append the strings to the previous key so it will look like Subjects=Computer Architecture;Advanced Network Security 2

Update: Thanks Ikegami for indicating that I use look behind operator. But I still seem to have problem solving it.

```
$line=~/^(?: ( [^:=]+ ) (?<!\s\s)\s* [:=]\s*|\s*)(.*)$/x;
```

So When I say `(?<!\s\s)\s* [:=]\s*|\s*` I mean when there more than two spaces, consume all the spaces and when there are no two consecutive spaces look for : or = and consume spaces. So   if you pass below line to the expression, Shouldnt I be getting $1=Name and $2=ABC XYZ?

```
Name         ABC XYZ
```

What I seem to be getting is key is empty and value is Name         ABC XYZ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

```
Name Eric Brine
Computer Architecture x86
```

means

```
key: Name Eric               value: Brine
key: Computer Architecture   value: x86
```

then you want

```
# Requires 5.10
if (/
   ^
   (?: (?<key> [^:=]+ (?<!\s) ) \s* [:=] \s* (?<val> .*  )
   |   (?<key> .+     (?<!\s) ) \s+          (?<val> \S+ )
   )
   \s* $
/x) {
   my $key = $+{key};
   my $val = $+{val};
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (/
   ^
   (?: ( [^:=]+ (?<!\s) ) \s* [:=] \s* ( .*  )
   |   ( .+     (?<!\s) ) \s+          ( \S+ )
   )
   \s*
   ( .* )
/x) {
   my ($key,$val) = defined($1) ? ($1,$2) : ($3,$4);
   ...
}
```

---

If

```
Name Eric Brine
Computer Architecture x86
```

means

```
key: Name       value: Eric Brine
key: Computer   value: Architecture x86
```

then you want

```
# Requires 5.10
if (/
   ^
   (?: (?<key> [^:=]+ (?<!\s) ) \s* [:=]
   |   (?<key> \S+ ) \s
   )
   \s*
   (?<val> .* )
/x) {
   my $key = $+{key};
   my $val = $+{val};
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (/
   ^
   (?: ( [^:=]+ (?<!\s) ) \s* [:=]
   |   ( \S+ ) \s
   )
   \s*
   ( .* )
/x) {
   my $key = defined($1) ? $1 : $2;
   my $val = $3;
   ...
}
```

---

Note that you can remove all the space and line breaks. For example, the last snippet can be written as:

```
if (/^(?:([^:=]+(?<!\s))\s*[:=]|(\S+)\s)\s*(.*)/) {
   my $key = defined($1) ? $1 : $2;
   my $val = $3;
   ...
}
```

Comment: It could be simplified if you were ok with trimming the key, but my solution is already shorter than Junuxx's.

Comment: This does it! But I have no idea whats happening. I missed one of the requirements in the question, for line Computer Architecture, it takes Computer as key and Architecture as value. I would like Computer Architecture as key.

Comment: @learningtocode, Do you also want `Name Eric Brine` to take `Name` as key and `Eric Brine` as value?

Comment: That is  what the solution you suggested is doing now. If Eric and Bane are in different lines from Name, then yes, but if they are in the same line, all of it should go into key. Thanks ikegami, it solves most of the problem, may be I will be able to fix the rest if I understand your expression better. Will post what I find.

Comment: Not sure if that's a yes or no. Updated.

Comment: I meant no. But I would like the line Computer Architecture to be interpreted as key=Computer Architecture.value and colon to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the key part as two bits of text with an optional space in between;

```
$line =~ /([\w\(\)]*\s?[\w\(\)]*)\s*([=:]?)\s*(\S.*)?$/;
```

That should capture both one-word and two-word keys.

Comment: Also the key could be more than two words.

Comment: Both his and my code accept more than one word for the key when ":" or "=" is used, but it's impossible to accept keys with spaces for the third syntax (because there's no way to know which if `abc def ghi` means `abc: def ghi` or `abc def: ghi`).